# Split string at specific number of line

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to count how many lines my paragraph have.

```
const lines = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length
```

and lines is 42 in my case, which is fine.

My question is how to split this string into two strings at a specific line.

For example, I want to split string at the fifth line.

I want to show first 5 lines and want to hide rest of lines.

How I can do that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you please share it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `const lines = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);` will make lines an array of all the lines you have. Then you can use `slice` to grab parts of that array. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

So like:

```
const firstFiveLines = lines.slice(0,4);
```

At this point, you have an array of the first 5 lines, but if you want to show those, then you will need additional code to output those lines into the document.

Comment: are line breaks in `firstFiveLines`?

Comment: @A.L.  They will not be. The split removes the characters that it split on. So you can use a `join` to combine the lines back together like `const newText = firstFiveLines.join("\n");` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

Match first 3 lines.

```
str = `line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
`
str.match(/^(.+?\n){3}/gi)[0]
```